# Prevent Windows 8.1 Windows Update from restarting the computer?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

There are several questions and answers on this site about how to prevent Windows 8 from restarting automatically with Windows Updates.  I don't think I need to explain that we have more important things to do than capitulate to demands to restart.

Unfortunately, Windows 8.1 appears to have been reprogrammed so that none of the previously discussed methods of preventing Windows from restarting work anymore.

In the meantime, there must be a new way to prevent Windows 8.1 from restarting.

I previously followed these steps here: http://wind8apps.com/prevent-windows-8-reboot/, but it rebooted anyways.

I have not had this problem since before the Windows 8.1 upgrade, so it seems logical that Windows 8.1 automatically restarts in spite of what I did.  Why then, is Windows 8.1 still forcing my computer to reboot?  I think there must be something else I must do to stop it.

Comment: Can you please remove the commentary?  Its not productive.  The methods still work I just tested them on a virtual machine because I was curious why so many people are asking about blocking the 8.1 update ( 5 questions in the last week ).

Comment: @Ramhound, I removed the commentary as you requested.  I carefully followed the linked instructions before I upgraded to Windows 8.1.  I am editing my question to add more detailed information.

Comment: @Ramhound, can you tell me what methods you tested?  Did you test the methods described in the linked article.  If so, what could account for it working for you, but not for me?

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/questions/887706/how-to-disable-auto-upgrade-from-windows-8-0-to-8-1/887709#887709) I know works.  I never heard of that website won't be visiting it either.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to pick and choose which updates you want to be applied with windows update, the control panel seems to have more functionality than the full screen app so I'd try that first. I'm on mobile or I'd be more specific!

Edit: to be more clear, this will get rid of the need to restart, and then you can just turn off auto-update)

Comment: How does the author accomplish this exactly?  Please provide detailed instructions.