# How to disable auto-upgrade from Windows 8.0 to 8.1?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-upgrade

I want to stay with Windows 8.0, but I'm given a band notification which requests to confirm upgrade to Windows 8.1. The notification can be postponed only twice, third time it forces the upgrade.

*How can I stop Windows 8.0 from auto-upgrading to 8.1?*

**Note:** I understand that keeping Windows at 8.0 might not be optimal from some viewpoints, but the valid reason in my case is that I don't have enough disk space on **C:** and without purchasing a new SSD, the upgrade is very risky and the computer might not survive it.

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3400/why-please-only-post-one-answer-to-a-question). Our community consensus is a little different. Your two (great) answers are just variations of the same thing (permanently vs. temporarily) and really should just be one comprehensive post.

Comment: Go to control panel -> windows Updates -> change settings -> never check for updates. Uncheck the notification check box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Method 1

#### Stopping upgrade mechanism permanently:

1. In registry key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\UpgradeNotification**,
   set value **UpgradeAvailable** to `0`:

[image: ## Heading ##]

2. Reboot

If you already got trapped in band notification which cannot be cancelled, first get rid of it by **Method 2**, then return and use this **Method 1**.

## Method 2

#### Stopping upgrade mechanism temporarily (if forcing pop-up has appeared):

*If the notification appears without a **Postpone** option in the middle of your work, blocking all apps, and you do not want to restart your computer or install anything, you can remove it this way:*

1. **Launch Task Manager:**
   Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> and you will see that Task Manager opens beneath the notification, although its window remains unreachable.
2. **Switch to Task Manager:**
   Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to Task Manager. It will remain beneath the notification, but now it is controllable by keyboard.
3. **Remove displayed notification:**
   In Task Manager, using <kbd>↓</kbd> key (down arrow), highlight **Modern Setup Host** and press <kbd>Delete</kbd> key to terminate it. Your screen is no longer blocked by notification.
4. **Remove further notifications:**
   In Task Manager, kill process **Windows 8.1 Setup** (the root of all this trouble). This bought you time until next restart or until next run of scheduled task. Follow **Method 1** if you wish to stop process permanently.
5. **Disable the scheduled task** (optional):
   Scheduled task will restart the **Windows 8.1 Setup** process if you killed it. It runs at 20:00 so if you do not plan to reboot before that time, you should disable it.
   Start **Task Scheduler**, navigate to **Task Scheduler Library** → **Windows** → **Setup**, select task **8.1 auto install v2** and press **Disable**.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Run as administrator:

DisableAutoUpgrade.cmd:

```
sc config wuauserv start= disabled
sc stop wuauserv
```

EnableAutoUpgrade.cmd:

```
sc config wuauserv start= auto
sc start wuauserv
```

Not need Reboot)

[How to Stop Automatic Forced Upgrade from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1?](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-update-to-windows-8-1-for-free-notification-in-windows-8-store/)

Comment: Would be helpful to include the information from the link since your instructions are not actually located on the link this answer seems to be missing information.

Comment: The commands above disable/enable entire Windows Update service, don't they? I **don't recommend this** because Windows Update should be **kept enabled** unless there are serious reasons. And Windows 8.1 upgrade can definitely be stopped without disabling Windows Update service. The above recommendation could make computer vulnerable if it will be kept unpatched, therefore I'm downvoting.